# Regex password - small letter cannot be followed by small letter and vice versa

Tags: java, regex

So the specification is:

- 10 to 15 characters
- has at least 1 small letter
- has at least 1 big letter
- cannot have 2 small or 2 big letters in a row (small letter cannot be followed by small letter and big letter cannot be followed by big letter)

I thought that I could do this by having 5 to 7 pairs of characters and 1 optional at the beginning, so that gives 10 to 15 characters, but these (and many other tests) return false every time. Any ideas on the approach or maybe syntax is incorrect?

thanks

```
// regex expression
    private static final Pattern PASSWORD_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^([a-z0-9]?([A-Z0-9][a-z0-9]){5,7}) 
        | ([A-Z0-9]?([a-z0-9][A-Z0-9]){5,7})$");

    // testing
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(verifyPassword("123456789123"));
        System.out.println(verifyPassword("AaAaAaAaAaAa3"));
    }
     // function for checking
     static boolean verifyPassword(String password) {
        final Matcher matcher = PASSWORD_PATTERN.matcher(password);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
```

Comment: You can't use any special character (`& , - _ ^ é`)? Pretty harsh.

Comment: You really want to annoy your users, right? As with all password patterns , use lookaheads to check all your conditions.

Comment: Use `"(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?!.*(?:[A-Z]{2}|[a-z]{2}))\\p{Alnum}{10,15}"`

Comment: [`^(?!.*(?:[a-z]{2}|[A-Z]{2}))(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{10,15}$`](https://regex101.com/r/w9dvCN/1)

Comment: anything wrong with /^(?=[A-Za-z0-9]{10,15}$).*(?!([A-Z]{2})).*(?!([a-z]{2})).*(?=[A-Z]).*(?=[a-z]).*$/  ? I can't find a case which would fail

Comment: @marvel308 It fails on many test cases, [here is one](https://regex101.com/r/cWhwzK/3). The problem is the `.*` at the start and end of the consuming pattern. All restricting lookaheads *must* be placed at the pattern start, right after the `^`.

Comment: ok thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `.matches()` method that requires a full string match, you may use

```
"(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?!.*(?:[A-Z]{2}|[a-z]{2}))\\p{Alnum}{10,15}"
```

**Details**

- `^` - implicit since the pattern is used inside `.matches()` method - start of string
- `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` - there must be an uppercase ASCII letter after any 0+ chars other than uppercase ASCII letters
- `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])` - there must be a lowercase ASCII letter after any 0+ chars other than lowercase ASCII letters
- `(?!.*(?:[A-Z]{2}|[a-z]{2}))` - no 2 consecutive uppercase (`[A-Z]{2}`) or lowercase (`[a-z]{2}`) letters after any 0+ chars other than line break chars (`.*`)
- `\\p{Alnum}{10,15}` - 10 to 15 ASCII letters or digits
- `$`  - implicit - end of string.

See a [Java demo](http://ideone.com/qkfeno):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("aaaa", "zzzzzzz", "AaAaAaAaAaAa3", "123456789123");
String pat = "(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?!.*(?:[A-Z]{2}|[a-z]{2}))\\p{Alnum}{10,15}";
for (String str : strs)
    System.out.println(str + ": " + str.matches(pat));
```

Output:

```
aaaa: false
zzzzzzz: false
AaAaAaAaAaAa3: true
123456789123: false
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?!.*[A-Z][A-Z])(?!.*[a-z][a-z]).{10,15}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vZ1NSU/3)